# Можно ли на ubuntu 20.04 создать свой вариант конфигурации кнопок на клавиатуре?

Tags: ubuntu, клавиатура, apple

При выборе языка в ubuntu 20.04 можно выбрать разные конфигурации, к примеру вот скрин с американским английским
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

можно ли создать что то подобное под себя?
Проблема в том что я использую мак клавиатуру и некоторые клавиши не совпадают, если поставить английский(мак) тоже

Comment: Вам нужна картинка другая или нужно кнопки переназначить?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, переназначить кнопки

Comment: Можно одназначно, как-то делал. Попробуйте загуглить что-нить аля https://google.com/search?q=ubuntu+remap+keyboard+keys.